# Store single instance in DbContext with ASP.NET MVC 5 CF EF (no list)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first

I have a class called **AppSettings** where I store some settings of my application. So far, I only used Lists in my DbContext like

```
public class MyDbContext: DbContext {
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; get; }
}
```

But for the settings, I need *no* list. I only want to store a single instance of my AppSettings class. I tried to set it as a normal member

```
public class AppSettingsContext: DbContext {
    public AppSettings AppSetting { get; get; }
}
```

But this is not working: EF will throw an exception that the entity type **AppSettings** is not a part of the model for the current context. The Code:

```
using(var db = new AppSettingsContext()) {
    var setting = new AppSettings() {
        AttributeA = "Test",
        //...
    };
    db.Entry(setting).State = EntityState.Added;
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Is it possible to do this with EF? Or am I forced to implement this logic on my own by using a not mapped attribute where I make sure that only one single instance is stored and returned by the database?

Comment: Why not use `DbSet`? You're already using a database that supports tables with multiple rows, might as well use a collection in C#.

Comment: I want to group my settings, which results in different models: UserSettings, RegistrationSettings and so on. With a DbSet, I have a list of each setting class. This require me to use an index, check if the index exists etc. I would like a single setting to access like `new AppSettingsContext().RegistrationSettings.IsEnabled`

Comment: Why use a database then? Sounds like what you would do with web.config. Secondly: why not just use DbSet and then store inside of a static class the id's of the settings so you can just make somthing like. DbContext.Settings.FirstAsync(s => s.id == MyStaticClass.UserSettigns)

You could even create an extension method to make it even more readable. Long sory short, no you can't store single values, it's a DB, that's not how they work

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store your settings in the DB, you can't store singular, that's not how TSQL works.

If you only want singular settings for a user, I would recomend web.config. If you REALLY want to store it in the DB though and want it to have a more concrete feeling you could just extend your database context like so:

```
public class MyDbContext: DbContext {
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; get; }
    public DbSet<AppSettings> AppSettings { get; set;}
}

public static class MyDbExtensions
{
    public static async Task<AppSettings> DbSettings(this MyDbContext context, Guid settingsGuid)
    {
        return await context.AppSettings.FirstAsync(as => as.Id == settingsGuid)
    }

    // OR
    public static async Task<AppSettings> UserSettings(this MyDbContext context)
    {
        return await context.AppSettings.FirstAsync(as => as.Id == UserSettingsDbGuid)
    }
    public static Guid UserSettingsDbGuid = "Guid of user settings goes here"
}

// example usage:
var context = GETDBCONTEXTMETHOD();
var userSettings == context.DbSettings(MyDbExtensions.UserSettingsDbGuid);
// OR
userSettings == context.UserSettings();
```